# New App Not Showing up in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-id

I have just created a new app in iTunes Connect. After it was created, my Browser crashed and I had to restart it. After I logged in to iTunes Connect, my newly created app wasn't visible.
I have also created an App ID in the Apple Developer Programm and thought to delete everything in the Apple Developer Section and recreate it.
When I want to delete my App ID, an error message occurs:

The App ID 'xxx' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it can not be removed at this time.

Now I can't delete my App ID and I can't see the created App in iTunes Connect?
Can anybody help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, you might think is related to your browser crash but it might not.

There are two things that you can try:

1.- If you haven't uploaded any Build yet, you can try uploading one, from XCode or App Loader doesn't matter, just upload a build and after some minutes see if your app finally gets to appear in list.

2.- If you happen to have more apps(any status), you can click on one of them to see the detail, and check if this missing app appears on the top App list, as in the image below:

[image]

This appears to be happening to more people: [Apple Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64156)

Comment: Im happy to hear that, remember to chose the answer if this solved completely your problem. Thanks!!